# How to solve Tabula error reading pdf to pandas?

Tags: python

Help. I am having the following error in reading pdf files using tabula:

> Error importing jpype dependencies. Fallback to subprocess.
> No module named 'jpype'
> Error from tabula-java:
> The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
> Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

i'm using a macbook with the following code:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(link_scrape['pdfs'],'*.pdf')):
    try:
        df = read_pdf(file,pages='all')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    break
```

how do i resolve this?

Comment: As like the error suggests, Can you try installing `jpype`?

Comment: As outlined in the docs https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html jpype is optional, it just makes tabula faster. Tabula however requires a Java runtime and the JAVA_HOME environment variable set in any case.